# How to get the text equally separated from the headrule and footrule with geometry?

Tags: header-footer, geometry

In the following MWE I'd like to define a dimen, `usep`, and do the blue margins (`uhsep` and `ufsep`) be equal to it, and `ubsep` (in green) to the half of it, when footnotes are to be printed. Otherwise, `uhsep` and `ubsep` should be equal to `usep`. Note that the distances should be measured from the `headrule`, `footnoterule` and `footrule`. Nor the `headrule` neither the `footrule` should be moved.

After the comments, I've achieved the basic layout (`uhsep`=`ubsep`=`usep`) with `headsep`, `bottom` and `footskip`:

```
%pages without footnotes
\def\usep{1cm}
\newdimen\hsep  \setlength{\hsep}{\dimexpr\usep+.3\baselineskip\relax}
\newdimen\fskip \setlength{\fskip}{\dimexpr\usep+.9\baselineskip\relax}
\newdimen\bmar \setlength{\bmar}{2.5cm} \addtolength{\bmar}{\dimexpr\usep-30pt+.9\baselineskip\relax}
\newgeometry[left=3.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=\bmar, headsep=\hsep, footskip=\fskip, showframe]{geometry}
```

[image: MWE post-processed with GIMP]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\setheadrule[1]{%
  \ifdim#1=\z@ \let\makeheadrule\@empty
  \else \def\makeheadrule{{\color{red}\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{#1}}} \fi}
\renewcommand\setfootrule[1]{%
  \ifdim#1=\z@ \let\makefootrule\@empty
  \else \def\makefootrule{\color{red}\rule[.9\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{#1}} \fi}
\makeatother

\newpagestyle{main}{ \headrule \footrule
 \sethead[][][\color{red}\sffamily Chapter title] %even
 {\color{red}\sffamily Section title}{}{} %odd
 \setfoot[\color{red}\sffamily\thepage][][\color{red}\sffamily Degree] %even
 {\color{red}\sffamily Theis title}{}{\color{red}\sffamily\thepage} %odd
} 

\begin{document}

%Change seps, skips...

\pagestyle{main}
\lipsum[1-2]
\footnote{This is a footnote}
\lipsum[3-4]
\footnote{This is another footnote}
\lipsum[5-7]

\end{document}
```

Solution using titlesec and geometry which provides a command `\updategeometry{<tbmargin>}{<sep>}`, where `<tbmargin>` is the top and bottom margin, measured to the main head and foot rules, and  is the separation from the rules to the text.

```
\def\chapv{1cm} \def\usep{0cm}
\def\tbmargin{\dimexpr\usep+\chapv\relax}
\def\hsep{\dimexpr.3\baselineskip+\usep\relax}
\def\fskip{\dimexpr.9\baselineskip+\usep\relax}

\newcommand\updategeometry[2]{
 \def\chapv{#1} \def\usep{#2}
 \newgeometry{left=3.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=\tbmargin, bottom=\tbmargin, headsep=\hsep, footskip=\fskip}
}
```

Comment: This will result in uneven pages because you'll have more space at the bottom of some pages than others. Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: I'd like to consider the footnotes as 'part of the footer' rather than 'part of the text' (`ubsep` may be rather small when footnotes are shown). On the other hand, when footnotes are not displayed, I want the body of the text to be smaller in pages when the Table of Contents and Lists of Figures/Tables are shown. Having `uhsep` and `ubsep` equal centers the content in the page.

Comment: But when you have a longer footnote, it will use part of the space otherwise used by the body. So it cannot look like 'part of the footer', can it? There's no problem using a different layout for the toc, tof, tot etc. if you really wish to. The footnote issue is a lot trickier. I don't say it cannot be done. But I do think it will not be at all straightforward.

Comment: Do you mean getting to know in which pages the footnotes are going to be shown is difficult? I can understand it, since the layout affects placing them and vice versa. If so, could you help me just to have `ubsep` equal to `uhsep`? Should it be something like `\addtolength{\textheight}{-(\usep-\footskip)}`?

Comment: Hang on. I'll have a look. That should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the modified question in the comments - not to your original question. I think the original question would be far from straightforward, if it can be done at all.

I think this is right but I'm not sure. You need to set `\ulength` to half of the value you want for the dimension you mentioned. `geometry` is then used to set the `headsep` and `footskip` and `fancyhdr` is used to manage the headers and footers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}
\newlength{\ulength}
\setlength{\ulength}{5mm}
\geometry{left=3.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, footskip=2\ulength, headheight=30pt, headsep=\ulength, showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhf[loh]{\color{red}\sffamily Section title}%
  \fancyhf[reh]{\color{red}\sffamily Chapter title}%
  \fancyhf[lof]{\color{red}\sffamily Thesis title}%
  \fancyhf[rof,lef]{\color{red}\sffamily\thepage}%
  \fancyhf[ref]{\color{red}\sffamily Degree}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{%
    \color{red}\rule[\ulength]{\headwidth}{\headrulewidth}}%
  \renewcommand{\footrule}{%
    \color{red}\rule[\dimexpr-2\ulength]{\headwidth}{\footrulewidth}\vss}}

\begin{document}

%Change seps, skips...

\pagestyle{main}
\lipsum[1-2]
\footnote{This is a footnote}
\lipsum[3-4]
\footnote{This is another footnote}
\lipsum[5-7]

\end{document}
```

[image: equal distance to head and foot rules]

Note that I used `fancyhdr` because it is easier to layout the page consistently. Moreover, `fancyhdr` tells you if things are going to go wrong because there is not enough space and so on.

I used `geometry` to set `footskip` etc. because, if you are using the package at all, you need to use it to make changes to the page layout. Otherwise, it doesn't know you've changed things and cannot take those changes into account when calculating lengths. So even when you are specifying 'native' dimensions such as `footskip`, make sure to do it using `geometry`.

## Update

To get the chapter and section titles automatically included in the header, I would do something like the following. This is partly because I'm just not very familiar with `titlesec` and have never used it for headers and footers. I mainly used `fancyhdr` because it tells you if the size of the header or footer is too small and tells you how large it needs to be. This was useful in laying out the page appropriately. However, I cannot see any reason why you could not substitute the facilities of `titleps` and drop `fancyhdr` if you prefer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newlength{\ulength}
\setlength{\ulength}{5mm}
\geometry{left=3.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, footskip=2\ulength, headheight=30pt, headsep=\ulength}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhf[loh]{\color{red}\sffamily \rightmark}%
  \fancyhf[reh]{\color{red}\sffamily \leftmark}%
  \fancyhf[lof]{\color{red}\sffamily Thesis title}%
  \fancyhf[rof,lef]{\color{red}\sffamily\thepage}%
  \fancyhf[ref]{\color{red}\sffamily Degree}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{%
    \color{red}\rule[\ulength]{\headwidth}{\headrulewidth}}%
  \renewcommand{\footrule}{%
    \color{red}\rule[\dimexpr-2\ulength]{\headwidth}{\footrulewidth}\vss}}


\begin{document}

%Change seps, skips...

\pagestyle{main}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{#1}}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\footnote{This is a footnote}
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[3-4]
\footnote{This is another footnote}
\lipsum[5-12]

\end{document}
```

[image: headers and footers with marks]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I'm using `titlesec` to set the titles of chapters and sections. Although I've used `fancyhdr` in other documents, I'd prefer to avoid loading more packages (if possible). However, I'll keep this as a reference, in case I can't get it done just with `titlesec` and `geometry`.

Comment: If I use `fancyhdr` to define pagestyles instead of `titlesec`, `\sectiontitle` and `\chaptertile` won't work, even if I load `\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}`. I'd like to show those instead of 'Chapter title' and 'Section title' in your example. Is it possible or should change `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`?

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral See my edit. I imagine you could substitute `titleps` if you wish. I'm just not very familiar with that package and don't have time to look at it right now so I've given you a quick solution with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: That's enough. It was just curiosity about how those are defined, since they seem clearer to me than `leftmark` and `rightmark`. Thanks again for your replies.